# Confluent Platform for Kubernetes - Error: failed to download "confluentinc/confluent-for-kubernetes"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

In my pursuit of being able to deploy Confluent Platform on Kubernetes I'm following along the "Quickstart" from the the Confluent page:

"https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-quickstart.html"

I am executing these steps:

```
helm repo add confluentinc https://packages.confluent.io/helm
helm repo update


helm upgrade --install confluent-operator confluentinc/confluent-for-kubernetes
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: failed to download "confluentinc/confluent-for-kubernetes"
```

I believe that the failure at this step is preventing me from proceeding onto installing the Confluent Platform (the target is AWS EKS).

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as a wrapper chart with my `Chart.yaml` as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: ccloud-connect
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: 1.0.0
description: Based on tutorial at https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/hybrid/ccloud-connect-confluent-hub
dependencies:
  - name: "confluentinc/confluent-for-kubernetes"
    version:  "0.771.13"
    repository: 'https://packages.confluent.io/helm'
```

When I tried to update the Helm dependencies I got a similar error message.

```bash
➜ helm dep up .

Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami-labs" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "aws" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Error: confluentinc/confluent-for-kubernetes chart not found in repo https://packages.confluent.io/helm
```

After some trial and error I got this working by removing `confluentinc` from the `name` field inside the `dependencies` list in the `Chart.yaml` file i.e.

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: ccloud-connect
version: 1.0.0
appVersion: 1.0.0
description: Based on tutorial at https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/hybrid/ccloud-connect-confluent-hub
dependencies:
  - name: "confluent-for-kubernetes"
    version:  "0.771.13"
    repository: 'https://packages.confluent.io/helm'
```

... then re-running `helm dep up` was successful ...

```bash
➜ helm dep up .

Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami-labs" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "aws" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Saving 1 charts
Downloading confluent-for-kubernetes from repo https://packages.confluent.io/helm
Deleting outdated charts
```

I then could `helm template` / `helm upgrade` etc without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem, but to solve that you can check first from where your repo is going to so i notice this in my when i run the

```
$ helm repo list
NAME                            URL
confluentinc                    https://confluentinc.github.io/cp-helm-charts/
```

SO as you can see the right URL shoud be `https://packages.confluent.io/helm` but instead i had the `https://confluentinc.github.io/cp-helm-charts/`

So in order to solve that we should first remove the wrong repo then add the right one, so for that i took the follow steps:

```
$ helm repo remove confluentinc

"confluentinc" has been removed from your repositories
```

Then:

```
helm repo add confluentinc https://packages.confluent.io/helm

"confluentinc" has been added to your repositories
```

For that solve the problem, hope help some guys as well.

#Keep Hacking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: "v0.2.19"
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: app name
# noinspection HelmChartUnknownValues
version: "v0.2.19"

dependencies:
  - name: confluent-for-kubernetes
    version: 0.771.13
    repository: https://packages.confluent.io/helm
    condition: kafka.enabled
```